# Textfield values deleted when scrolling tableview?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have tableview cell with a textfield but when I add new row and scroll tableview up or down disappeared textfield values deleted. I make lots of research about that previous question about that in 2015 and its not answered correctly. How can I fix this issue? How can I use textfield delegate method if it is working for this? Here my code:

```
var i = 0

while i <= taskArrForRead.count {
  let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
  let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? taslakDuzenlemeCell

  if let item = cell?.taslakTextField.text! {
    arrayOfNames.append(item)
  }
  i = i + 1
}
```

In this code I get all textfield values from tableview but if tableview scroll disappeared values turn with default values. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Here my tableview code:

```
extension taslakOlusturmaController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return taskArrForRead.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taslakCell", for: indexPath) as! taslakDuzenlemeCell

        cell.taslakTextField.text = taskArrForRead[indexPath.item]
        cell.taslakTextField.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print(textField.text!)
        self.arrayOfNames.append(textField.text!)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taslakCell", for: indexPath) as! taslakDuzenlemeCell
        cell.taslakTextField.text = taskArrForRead[indexPath.item]
        print(arrayOfNames[indexPath.item])
    }
}
```

With `textfield delegate` method I can get deleted textfield values but I can't bring it again to textfield. User can't see value after scroll again also I can get deleted values with `didEndDisplaying cell` method too.

Comment: its because the cell is reuse, you need to save textfield value in a variable inside viewcontroller

Comment: Show your tableView code

Comment: @NayanDave Here I added.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method `PrepareForReuse` to set the text back when the cell recreated again.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. How can I exactly use it? Need I call textfield in this method? Sorry about that I'm new in swift.